# how to update data when app is terminated

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

Is there any way to grab the information that comes from the firebase notification when the app is closed in the background?

I managed to capture it and save it in the following function

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
```

when it is in the background and in execution, but I cannot do it when it is closed

I managed to capture it and save it in the following function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to do.

When the app is sent to the background there are certain [life cycle changes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle) that happen and the AppDelegate is notified about this, which gives you a chance to do some small tasks like cleanup, or make a last minute save. But you will only get a limited time to do so (I think its usually around 1 minute, you can ask for more time I believe but that only extends it to about 3 mins).

An example of these life cycle events is [applicationWillTerminate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623111-applicationwillterminate), this method is called just before the app terminates and gives you a small window to make a last minute save.

Once your app is suspended you can only do limited things, like background fetch, receive location information, receive push notifications etc.

[Background Modes](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5817-background-modes-tutorial-getting-started) is a good guide on what you can do in the background

**When your app is terminated**, there is pretty much nothing you can do.